# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Order' not found in C:\apache\htdocs\inventory_manager\app\public\index.php:17

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm creating an app to use autoload in composer.json to load my class files. I was getting 
`Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Order' not found in C:\apache\htdocs\inventory_manager\app\public\index.php:17`

I checked the path of the $vendorDir folder relative to my $baseDir in the vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php and its correct. I've checked through threads with similar issues but still. Thanks in advance

This is my composer.json file

```
{
  "name": "inventory manager",
  "description": "Inventory Management System",
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my folder Structure

```
 |---inventory_manager
     |---app
         |---Model
             |---DatabaseObject.php
             |---Order.php
             |---Product.php
     |---public
         |---assets
             |---css
         |---index.php
     |---vendor
     |---composer.json
```

Order.php

```php
namespace App;

class Order
{
  private $name;
  private $brand;
  private $shape;


  function __construct($name,$brand, $shape)
  {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->brand = $brand;
    $this->shape = $shape;
  }

  public function toString()
  {
    return "{$this->name}, {$this->brand}, {$this->shape}";
  }
}
```

index.php

```php
<?php
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';

  $prdt = new App\Order('Civic', 'Honda', 'Classic');

  var_dump($prdt);
```

Comment: Does index.php have a namespace? (in case it was edited out for this example)

Comment: the public dir is within the app dir

Comment: Also it looks like the `order` class needs to be in the `\app\Model\Order` namespace.

Comment: No please @NicholasSummers

Comment: Yes it is @NicholasSummers

Comment: In the code above you have `namespace App;` so it's not in `\app\Model\Order` it is in `\app\Order`

Comment: I changed the ```namespace App``` to ```namespace App\Model```  as @NicholasSummers suggested and it worked. thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong namespace set for your `Order` class.

Replace `namespace App;` with `namespace App\Model;`